# Remote desktop display shifted up

Tags: remote-desktop

I use the Microsoft Remote Desktop Client (ver 8.0.31) to connect from my 2013 Retina Macbook Pro (OSX 10.11.4) to a Windows 10 desktop machine. When in fullscreen mode, I get the following experience:

[image]

The display is shifted up by about 10 pixels, resulting in a black bar at the bottom of the screen and the top of the screen being cut-off.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with 8.0.x.

There's a beta currently in progress for a completely re-developed Microsoft Remote Desktop, currently on 8.2.22, which fixes almost all the known bugs with the existing app. You can download the latest beta here:

- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619698

Comment: Note the beta does not work on Yosemite, so if you still have a machine running that...

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop 10 works with 2 finger tap. (help menu suggestion does not work <kbd>^ Control</kbd> click: Press and hold the <kbd>^ Control</kbd> key while you click an item.) (MacOS Mojave 10.14.3)